# I need some explanation on this assembly code

Tags: assembly

Hi I have wrote a function that clears an array by its index and generated the assembly code.

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_i$ = -8                        ; size = 4
_arr$ = 8                       ; size = 4
_size$ = 12                     ; size = 4
?clear_arr@@YAXQAHH@Z PROC              ; clear_arr, COMDAT

; 3    : void clear_arr(int arr[], int size){

push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 204                ; 000000ccH
push    ebx
push    esi
push    edi
lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-204]
mov ecx, 51                 ; 00000033H
mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
rep stosd

; 4    :    int i;
; 5    :    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){

mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], 0
jmp SHORT $LN3@clear_arr
$LN2@clear_arr:
mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
add eax, 1
mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], eax
$LN3@clear_arr:
mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
cmp eax, DWORD PTR _size$[ebp]
jge SHORT $LN4@clear_arr

; 6    :        arr[i]=0;

mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
mov ecx, DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp]
mov DWORD PTR [ecx+eax*4], 0

; 7    :    }

jmp SHORT $LN2@clear_arr
$LN4@clear_arr:

; 8    : }

pop edi
pop esi
pop ebx
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret 0
?clear_arr@@YAXQAHH@Z ENDP              ; clear_arr
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

I need some explanation about the loop part. Another thing that I want to know is about DWORD PTR and the register in square bracket line [ebp]. If a register is placed in a square bracket, is it represent the address of that register?? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registers don't have addresses themselves, but they may hold an address (a pointer) to a memory location.

The format used by your compiler seems to include a list (at the top) of parameters and local variables and their offsets relative to the address stored in `ebp`.

So `mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], 0` means: Store `0x00000000` at address `ebp-8` (which is where the local variable `i` resides). The square brackets are similar to dereferencing a pointer in C. You need the specifier `DWORD PTR` because you could also want to simply store a single byte, i.e. `0x00`, in that case you'd use `BYTE PTR`.

`mov ecx, DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp]` moves the dword value at `ebp+8` to `ecx` (as you can see from the list at the top, `_arr` corresponds to `8`). In terms of your C program, `ebp+8` holds `&arr[0]`. The dollar sign is a feature of the particular compiler assembly syntax that you use. The more common way to write that statement would be `mov ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]`, but the syntax you have has the advantage of directly telling you which local variable it corresponds to.

About the loop construct, you should probably clarify what exactly your question is there.

Comment: So mov ecx, DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp] means that move the value in DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp] into the register ecx?? And can you explain what is the dollar sign means?? ex. DWORD PTR _i$[ebp] Thanks

Comment: @eChung00 Updated my answer with a paragraph about this.

Comment: Now it is getting clear... I am sorry to keep bother you but have one more question.. why is it 8?? The array type is int.. which I know that it is 4 byte each.. then you said that ebp+8 holds the address &arr[0] then ebp+16 holds the address &arr[1] and so on.. why is it 8?? thanks

Comment: No, `ebp+8` holds `&arr[0]`, **NOT** `arr[0]`, i.e. it holds the pointer to the beginning to the array. `ebp+16` has no significance in your function, if you want the second element, you need to dereference first: `mov ecx, [ebp+8]` - now `ecx` has the pointer to the first element, `add ecx, 4` - now `ecx` has the pointer to the second element, and you can now extract it to `eax` for example via `mov eax, [ecx]`.